# How to Import Data from excel to SPSS

Tags: excel, import, spss

Sorry if the title is ambiguous or repetitive, but my question is kinda different.

I know how to import data file form excel to SPSS, and by default SPSS reads variable name from excel first row.

My question is that, in SPSS can we specify from which row to read variable names instead of only first row (From 2nd row or third).

For eg:

Excel file I am having have variable names in 3rd row and data from 4th  row onward. And when I am importing in SPSS, I only get an option to read variable name from first row (that is vacant in excel). I want to specify that SPSS reads variable name from 3rd row not first row.

---------------xxx----------------

By Directly I mean, when I import through SPSS shortcuts and not via syntax editor.

Syntax used by me (Giving me Error):

```
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX
  /FILE='C:\Users\nikhil.gupta\Desktop\Jaspercolin_Barometer_Study_Excel_07Mar15_595Comp.xlsx'
  /SHEET= name 'RID to QIName'
  /CELLRANGE= RANGE 'A6:JB601'
  /READNAMES=on
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.
DATASET NAME DataSet20 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

And Syntax when I do the import via SPSS Shortcut(Working):

```
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX
  /FILE='C:\Users\nikhil.gupta\Desktop\Jaspercolin_Barometer_Study_Excel_07Mar15_595Comp.xlsx'
  /SHEET=name 'RID to QIName'
  /CELLRANGE=full
  /READNAMES=on
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.
DATASET NAME DataSet1 WINDOW=FRONT.
```

Error I am getting:

```
Error.  Command name: GET DATA 
(2063) Error reading information for sheet. 
* Sheet Name: "RID to QIName" 
Execution of this command stops.
```

Its reading sheet name When I import via SPSS, but doesn't when I do the same via syntax editor. I guess error points to the same condition, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. So when you import data via GUI File-->`Open`-->`Data`-->`Select Excel Data file`

You will be presented with the following GUI:

(EDIT: Image upload doesn't seem to be working?!)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ni2jdjs36lxwb16/SOImportExcelToSPSSRangeGUI.bmp?dl=0

[image]

Where you can see the "Range" option which allows you to manually enter a continuous range to select the data from in the Excel file.

So below is the syntax that would be generated:

```
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX 
  /FILE='C:\Users\JigneshSutar\Documents\ImportExcelToSPSS.xlsx' 
  /SHEET=name 'Sheet1' 
  /CELLRANGE=range 'A2:V129' 
  /READNAMES=on 
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.
```

If not manually selecting a range then SPSS automatically reads the used range in excel and imports that range only. The syntax used for that is `CELLRANGE=FULL`

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for solving my query, but when I am trying to run the same, I am getting an error despite of doing the same thing.

Comment: What exactly is the error message you receive? Please share. Have you checked to ensure the file name and Excel cell range are valid?

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for solving my query, but when I am trying to run the same, I am getting an error despite of doing the same thing.
GET DATA /TYPE=XLSX
  /FILE='Z:\Tabulation\2015\Conversion\Barometer_Study\Rqtdocs\09-03-2015\Jaspercolin_Barometer_Study_Excel_07Mar15_595Comp.xlsx'
  /SHEET=name 'RID to QIName'
  /CELLRANGE=RANGE 'A6:JB601'
  /READNAMES=on
  /ASSUMEDSTRWIDTH=32767.

Data start from A6 cell and my sheet name is 'RID to QIName'. Error say unable to read excel sheet (error 2063).

I am not getting the error when I import directly , but when I try to import via syntax, I get the error.

Comment: Perhaps update your original post with syntax as it is not readable as a comment. Why not compare the manually modified syntax vs. the syntax generated when importing directly? If it can be imported directly it can be imported by syntax (If not, then assume error in the syntax). What exactly do you mean by "directly" also?

Comment: Also best to share the entire error message on not just the number? I'm assuming the error message contain further more details that could be insightful than just an error number?

Comment: Hi,
I have edited my question and wrote down the error I am getting, along with code.(Please look into question after -----------xxxxxx------ ) 
Please tell me the mistake made by me?

Comment: Have no idea. Maybe post your excel file? Check sheet name case sensitivity match.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry for all the trouble, but I am able to do the import now. Only thing I am unable to do yet is variable names from the excel data file

Comment: Variable names will be imported from row 6 of the excel file as that is the start of where you have requested the data pull from. If variable names are in row 1 and data starts row 6, you have to import all rows (including between 2-5) and then delete these redundant rows after.

Comment: I start from cell A6, and that's where my Variable name starts
and from A7 my data starts. 
All the rows above A6 contain useless information. I am able to do the import, but SPSS do not read the variable names. Logically it should, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it should as expected. If content in that cell doesn't conform to SPSS variable name convention then it will automatically make some decisions to covert it so that it does. Please always provide more detailed information so what is in the content in the cells in row 6 and what is it that is being imported into SPSS? Even better to share a sample of the Excel file.

Comment: It contains proper names, like RID, Completion Status, and so on.They do meet SPSS naming convention,